# git log excluding certain committers

Tags: git

`git log --author=<pattern>` limits the output to commits with specified authors.

I am looking for a way to list commits *excluding* those by a small set of users.

The reason is that there is an infrastructure group that makes non-functional changes, tagging files, changing version numbers etc. I want to exclude them.

It does not seem like this can be done with `git log`. Any other suggestions?